# Unable to download pdf weblinks using org.apache.commons.io java library

Tags: java, apache, file-io, download, pdf-generation

I am trying to download PDF weblinks using org.apache.commons.io library java.
I want download 'https://----------------.pdf'  intp pdf file, when I run following java class it creates the destination pdf on my disk but I am unable to open or read that pdf. It throws an error file is corrupted or unable to read.

I would appreciate if somebody will check whats wrong in my code and how to download pdf weblinks in to pdf file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://docs.google.com/**********.pdf");
            File destination = new File("kodejava.html");

            //
            // Copy bytes from the URL to the destination file.
            //
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to save .pdf file as .html file?

Comment: Have you inspected the contents of your file?

Comment: if destination file id pdf , it creates but I canot open it throws an error corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your file as a pdf, not an html.Try renaming the downloaded file as kodejava.pdf and open. I am able to download it as .pdf and open it.

Comment: I changed to 'kodejava.pdf ' but created pdf is unable to open it throws an error corrupted file

Comment: i tried this site - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_tutorial.pdf. it worked. May be you have no permission

Comment: it worked because it starts with www. , site that starts with https:// doesnt work

Comment: were you able to open it in browser without authentication?

Comment: It opens in broswer but blank black page.

Comment: is it possible to do this with iText and org.apache.commons.io., apahe to read https url and iText to write it into pdf. I tried that but throws an exception